# Подсчет строк в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Использую для подсчета COUNT, нужно посчитать сколько комментариев к каждой записи и вывести на главную. Проблема в том, что подсчет идет всех комментариев и к каждой записи выводится общее количество всех комментариев.
***К примеру:***
write1 - 1 комментарий
write2 - 3 комментария
write3 - 2 комментария
***А выводит вот так:***
write1 - 6 комментариев
write2 - 6 комментариев
write3 - 6 комментариев

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем виде запрос с расчетом кол-ва комментариев для каждого поста должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(c.write_id) AS `count`
FROM tweets t
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.write_id = t.id_post
GROUP BY t.id_post
```

UPD: Если конечно `comments.write_id` - это тоже что и `tweets.id_post`

Comment: вот именно данный код, выводит самое большое кол-во комментариев, если рассматривать пример выше, то выводит кол-во на всех комментариях - 3

Comment: В таком случае `c.write_id` не то поле которое должно хранить ID поста из таблицы `tweets`. Найди нужно поле и измени условие для LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Нет, не так. Ошибка в другом.

    SELECT count(comment_id) FROM comments WHERE t.id_post = c.write_id AND t.wallid = c.wall_id

В этом подзапросе таблица `comments` указана без алиаса `c`. А, так как, эта-же таблица используется и в LEFT JOIN то условие берет в учет внешнюю таблицу, а не ту что в подзапросе.

Замени:

    FROM comments

на:

    FROM comments c

Приоритет будет у алиаса объявленного внути подзапроса.

Comment: офигеть, спасибо большое... всё работает, даже и не подумал бы об comments c