# Подсчет заявок, находящихся в обработке

Tags: mysql, pdo

Приветствую.

Имеется следующая таблица БД:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `treatments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`places_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lc_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`fullname` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`tema` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`status` enum('1', '2', '3', '4') NOT NULL default '1',
`type` enum('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') NOT NULL default '1',
`priority` enum('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') NOT NULL default '1',
`control` enum('1', '2') NOT NULL default '1',
`del` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`replytime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sroktime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `places_id` (`places_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `lc_id` (`lc_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Необходимо подсчитать кол-во заявок, находящихся в обработке у определенного ответственного. lc_id - ID ответственного.

Такой запрос

```
SELECT `treatments`.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `treatments` WHERE `treatments`.`lc_id`=`users`.`id`) AS `treatmentscount` FROM `treatments` WHERE `places_id` IN (3, 1, 2) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

явно не верный.

Похожий вопрос про подсчет [Подсчет строк в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119839/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mysql) Но всё равно немного не то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хоть бы описание полей добавили...

Comment: Я же указал, что lc_id - ID ответственного. Собственно больше ничего и не нужно т.к. по нему нужно произвести подсчет.

Comment: Приведённый в текст запроса подзапрос ``SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `treatments` WHERE `treatments`.`lc_id`= :id `` полностью решает поставленную задачу *подсчитать кол-во заявок, находящихся в обработке у определенного ответственного. lc_id - ID ответственного.* Что ещё нужно-то?

Comment: Не решает, выдаёт ошибку "#1054 - Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: ну да, потому что у вас нет колонки users.id, у вас есть user_id

Comment: user_id - ID того, кто создал обращение.

Comment: Вот это например что должно выбрать? `lc_id`=`users`.`id`?

Comment: Да. Имеется таблица с пользователями users. Имеется таблица с обращениями treatments. обычным циклом выводятся обращения. И нужно в этом же цикле в этом же запросе подсчитать кол-во заявок, находящихся в обработке у определенного ответственного пользователя.

Comment: А у вас тут не опечатка?` WHERE `treatments`.`lc_id`=`users`.`id`) AS `treatmentscount` FROM `treatments`` Просто пытаюсь Ваш запрос разобрать)

Comment: Ну так я привёл пример не правильного запроса и поэтому задал вопрос.

Comment: Алё... тебе надо (по твоим же собственным словам) *подсчитать кол-во заявок, находящихся в обработке у **определенного** ответственного*. За каким фигом считать для всех-то? Фильтруй прямо по lc_id нужного тебе ответственного - и можно даже не группить.

Comment: Подсчитать для каждого ответственного. Обращения выводятся обыкновенным циклом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моё решение:

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `treatments` WHERE `treatments`.`lc_id`=`c`.`id`) AS `treatmentscount` FROM `treatments` t LEFT JOIN users c ON c.id = t.lc_id WHERE `t`.`places_id` IN (3, 1, 2) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]